# How to add Healthcheck endpoint to deploy openTelemetry collector behind GW in GKE?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gateway, health-check, open-telemetry-collector, opentelemetry-js

I deployed open-telemetry collector on my GKE cluster and want to send it traces from browser app,
therefor I need to expose it behind GW ,
the GW require healthcheck endpoint that return an health response ,
Is there any way to add healthcheck endpoint to open-telemetry collector?

I tried to add healthcheck extension in otel-collector config from [this repo](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/extension/healthcheckextension),

```
...
    service:
      extensions:  
        health_check:
          endpoint: "localhost:13133"
          path: "/health"
          check_collector_pipeline:
            enabled: true
            interval: "5m"
            exporter_failure_threshold: 5

...
```

and tried to access the pod in this endpoint : http://POD_IP:13133/health

but I didnt get any response.